# Deserializing nested XML list in RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I have response in XML in the following format:

```
<response>
  <projects>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
    <project>...</project>
  </projects>
</response>
```

I have created a 'Project' class with attributes that match the names of the tags inside the <project> tag of the XML. Since the <projects> tag contains a list of <project>s, I was trying to execute the request on the RestSharp client as:

`var projectList = client.Execute<List<Project> >(request);`

However, projectList.Data shows null. This makes sense because the deserializer wasn't able to find a 'Projects' class. But in segue, my question is: how do I get a list of <project>s when it is nested in another tag <projects>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Response` class, have a property `public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }`.

This way, it will map the `<projects>` to your property `Projects`.